# Accessing Hangfire Jobs throwing "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in .net core

Tags: asp.net, hangfire

I am using Hangfire to fetch jobs in Dot Net Core application to filter some specific jobs by method name.

this is the code I'm using

var api = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();

var processingJobs = api.ProcessingJobs(0, int.MaxValue); **----> throwing exception**

var anyProcessingJob = processingJobs.Any(x => x.Value.Job.Method.Name.Contains(method) && x.Value.Job.Type.Name.Contains(type));

[ExceptionMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvS7T.png)

How do I fix it?

Comment: You should give the type of the exception, as well as the exception message.
It would help.

Comment: Updated with exception message

Comment: Seems your problem comes from somewhere here :
https://github.com/arnoldasgudas/Hangfire.MySqlStorage/blob/master/Hangfire.MySql/Monitoring/MySqlMonitoringApi.cs#L181
I don't know about MySql implementation
First thing I would try is a lower value than Int.MaxValue
Seems Monitoring has a ProcessingCount() method. You should give a try

Comment: I tried that too but same issue. So I have created new Db and everything is working. But not working on old DB in local